# get error in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i has one problem in debug mode, but this problem Absence in run project.
my project base in jboss-javaee-webapp-ear-blank-archetype .

I run project in eclipse and run project with

```
mvn clean install package jboss-as:deploy
```

but run project receive down:

```
    09:54:55,262 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
09:54:56,080 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
09:54:56,144 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" starting
09:55:01,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] JBAS015003: Found Test-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Test-ear.ear.dodeploy
09:55:01,681 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.6.GA
09:55:01,689 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.6.GA
09:55:01,695 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.8.SP1
09:55:01,734 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
09:55:01,807 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
09:55:01,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:55:01,809 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
09:55:01,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011906: Activating OSGi Subsystem
09:55:01,814 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
09:55:01,819 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
09:55:01,984 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
09:55:02,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
09:55:02,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.12.Final)
09:55:02,319 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
09:55:02,358 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.13.Final
09:55:04,495 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
09:55:05,470 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.5.GA
09:55:06,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
09:55:06,160 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
09:55:06,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/aryana/Documents/Software-Portable/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/deployments
09:55:06,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Test-ear.ear"
09:55:06,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ojdbc6.jar"
09:55:06,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "eclipselink-2.5.0.jar"
09:55:06,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
09:55:06,597 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
09:55:07,501 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
09:55:07,507 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.ojdbc6.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
09:55:07,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jboss/datasources/OracleDS]
09:55:07,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011907: Register module: Module "deployment.eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
09:55:08,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Test-ejb.jar"
09:55:08,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Test-web.war"
09:55:08,279 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primaryTest
09:55:08,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primaryTest
09:55:08,405 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Test-ear.ear
09:55:08,466 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Test-ejb.jar
09:55:08,468 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-10) JNDI bindings for session bean named GetOrSetDataBase in deployment unit subdeployment "Test-ejb.jar" of deployment "Test-ear.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/Test-ear/Test-ejb/GetOrSetDataBase!business.GetOrSetDataBaseLocal
    java:app/Test-ejb/GetOrSetDataBase!business.GetOrSetDataBaseLocal
    java:module/GetOrSetDataBase!business.GetOrSetDataBaseLocal
    java:global/Test-ear/Test-ejb/GetOrSetDataBase
    java:app/Test-ejb/GetOrSetDataBase
    java:module/GetOrSetDataBase

09:55:08,493 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test-ear.ear"."Test-web.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test-ear.ear"."Test-web.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Test-web.war" of deployment "Test-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class manageBean.BeanForGetImageFromUser with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Test-ear.ear.Test-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/primefaces/model/UploadedFile;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile from [Module "deployment.Test-ear.ear.Test-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

09:55:08,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "eclipselink-2.5.0.jar"
09:55:08,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "Test-ear.ear"
09:55:08,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar"
09:55:08,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test-ear.Test-ejb.GetOrSetDataBase (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test-ear.Test-ejb.GetOrSetDataBase.Validator, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.Test-ear.Test-ejb.GetOrSetDataBase.ValidatorFactory] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test-ear.ear"."Test-web.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test-ear.ear"."Test-web.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Test-web.war" of deployment "Test-ear.ear"

09:55:08,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:55:08,866 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:55:08,866 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" started (with errors) in 14164ms - Started 212 of 308 services (5 services failed or missing dependencies, 89 services are passive or on-demand)
```

my method in debug mode is: mvn clean install package and right click on project and debug as> Debug On Server

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to dedug with maven tests try this in cmd or similar:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
```

and in eclipse prepare debug for remote java aplication with port 8000.

I hope it helps.

Generic Debugging

Select break points in the code you're are going to run.

Run Maven in debug mode, e.g `mvn-debug install`

Attach the debugger to the running maven by selecting the "Maven" debug configuration created above.

Eclipse will now stop Maven at the breakpoints you have enabled.
Setting up Maven 2.0.8+

Note: If you are using Maven 2.0.8 or newer, simply run the "`mvnDebug`" command in place of "mvn" and skip down to setting up Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, but I first want to debug that do and do not know what I should do. Please explain step by step. Thanks :(

Comment: take a look at this site, it depends or you maven version is easier, the up exemple is for debug test with maven, but you can change the last word. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Dealing+with+Eclipse-based+IDE